# JavaFX Textfield behind one character when grabbing text

Tags: java

This code below which is triggered by a typed key into a JavaFX textfield is always behind one character. For instance, if user types in k, the string printed for searchBar.getText() equals "". If a user types in another k it will equal "k", and so on.

```
   //this is triggered when a key is typed into search bar
        @FXML public void onKeyPressedOnSearch(){
            File[] fileCollection = model.getFileCollection();


            System.out.println(searchBar.getText());
            System.out.println(fileCollection[0].getName().substring(0, searchBar.getText().length()));
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            ObservableList<String> tempObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);


        /*  for(int i = 0; i < fileCollection.length; i++){
                if(!(searchBar.getText().equals(fileCollection[i].getName().substring(0, searchBar.getText().length())))){
                    tempObservableList.remove(i);
                }
            }


            if(searchBar.getText() == null || searchBar.getText() == ""){
                songList.setItems(observableList);
            }else{
                songList.setItems(tempObservableList);
            } */
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should listen to onKeyReleased?

Comment: @tsolakp I tried that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to add a `ChangeListener` to the `TextField`, so you can grab any change in it from there, Please consider this example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CharByCharGrabbing extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // create simple root and add two text fields to it
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        // just styling
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.MAGENTA, null,null)));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        TextField textField1 = new TextField();

        root.getChildren().addAll(textField, textField1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Grabbing Char by Char");
        stage.show();

        // Now you can add a change listener to the text property of the text field
        // it will keep you updated with every single change (char by char)
        // either adding to or removing from the TextField
        textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldText, newText)->{ // lambda style
            textField1.setText(newText); // update me when any change happens
            // so you can grab the changes from here.
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Test**

[image: Test]

Comment: Yes, this.  Listen to the `text` property, not to key presses!  Some systems even allow the user to change the text of a TextField using only the mouse.

Comment: @VGR Exactly, It will grab any change in the `TextField` either by pressing a key or using the mouse, as long as the text in the `TextField`changes.